# Referencing HTML Form Elements in cloned table rows

Tags: javascript

First of all, thanks in advance to all those who contribute to this post.  I am trying to understand two things in the JS code below: 1) why must I check for an "undefined" element in a table row object when there is only one row, if second and third row objects can be referenced with the [x] index value... is there a simpler way to do this? 2) how do i appropriately clear field values on clone rows (in the addRow() function. What I have works, but not sure if it's the right way to do clear values).

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/arperez/n6azm28k/7/

Here's the full script ("myTable" is within a FORM element named "myForm" inside the BODY tag):

```
function addRow() {
    var tblBody = document.getElementById("myTable").tBodies[0];
    var lastrow = tblBody.rows.length;
    var newNode = tblBody.rows[0].cloneNode(true);
    tblBody.appendChild(newNode);   
    
    //Clear copied values from cloned row.
    document.myForm.txtQty[lastrow].value = "";  //This works, but is this the right way to clear the textbox value of the cloned row?
}

function calcTotals() {
    
    var qty = 0;
    var totalqty = 0;
    var rows = document.getElementById("myTable").tBodies[0].rows.length - 1;
    
    for (i=0; i<=rows; i++) {
    
        var element = document.myForm.txtQty[i];
        if (element === undefined) {  //If I don't do this check I get an error when there is only one row existing in the table and I try referencing it with [0]. Not sure why?
            qty = document.myForm.txtQty.value;  //This works, but why does txtQty[0] not work? Is this the right way to refer to the first element/row?
        } else {
            qty = document.myForm.txtQty[i].value;
        }
        totalqty = totalqty + Number(qty);
    }
    
    //Display total quantities calculated
    alert("Total = " + totalqty);
}


<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
         <th>Quantity</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td><input type="number" id="txtQty" name="txtQty"></td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="addRow();">Add Row</button>
<button type="button" onclick="calcTotals();">Calculate Total</button>
```

Comment: Would you tell me what is the purpose for the following statement?

`var rows = document.getElementById("myTable").tBodies[0].rows.length - 1;`

Comment: The reason for that statement is to get a max number of rows that can work with the zero-based for loop that follows.

Comment: You're cloning something with an `#id` and having duplicate `#id`s is invalid HTML. Moreover, if you don't have any unexpected behavior now you will eventually. See MDN there's a yellow [warning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) note about it.

Comment: @zer00ne - if i give every element a unique id (as in txtQty1, txtQty2, etc.), how do i reference them in a for loop, especially if you keep in mind that some rows can be deleted? Any ideas?

Comment: That's exactly the problem if you use `getElementById()` or `querySelector()` those methods will quit searching after finding the first one and the rest will be ignored. If you reference by index...it should work, never had invalid HTML intentionally 

Comment: There are ways to do this more efficiently and valid just by using one `[name]` on all of your fields. I'll post later.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the beginning, you have only 1 element which name is "txtQty", so the  document.myForm.txtQty is not an array.
2. Your solution is ok.

Here is my implementation:

```js
function addRow() {
  var tblBody = document.getElementById("myTable").tBodies[0];
  var newRow = tblBody.rows[0].cloneNode(true);
  tblBody.appendChild(newRow);   
  let textBox=newRow.querySelector("input[name='txtQty[]']");
  textBox.value="";
}

function calcTotals() {
  var totalqty = 0;
  var qty = 0;
  var totalqty = 0;
  var txtQtys = document.getElementsByName('txtQty[]');
  for (i=0;i<txtQtys.length;i++){
    totalqty +=Number(txtQtys[i].value) ;
  } 
  alert("Total = " + totalqty);
}
```

```html
<body>
<form name="myForm">

    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
             <th>Quantity</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
             <td><input type="number" name="txtQty[]"></td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" onclick="addRow();">Add Row</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="calcTotals();">Calculate Total</button>

</form>
</body>
```

Comment: @KNVB - Thanks for the example you provided.  I do need to use the cloneNode method, given the number of elements I have in the row (although the example I posted originally only had one textbox for simplicity, I do have many HTML elements (textboxes, selects, checkboxes, etc.) in the row in real life).  I'd like to know how to reference the individual HTML elements in a loop if each object has a unique id/name.  I'm not sure how to do that... If you can post a sample of that I'll greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I have updated the code, please check

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a brief description highlighting this example and the rest will have references. No `#id`s were needed only `[name]` although `#id` wouldn't be a problem, unless they were cloned.

There are two event handlers, one for click events (`manageData(e)` and one for change events (`switchRow(e)`), both are bound to the form.

```
   const UI = document.forms.UI;
   UI.onclick = manageData;
   UI.onchange = switchRow;
```

There are two normal functions which are called from `manageData(e)`:

```
    addRow();
    sum(array);
```

`manageData(e)` delegates the click event to only specific tags and ignores the rest. It determines what the user clicked by using `event.target` property. It also references the form with `e.currentTarget` as the tag listening for click events. With the addition of the `.elements` property, you can access all form controls within the form. Moreover, you can reference a specific group that shares the same `[name]` attribute. The form interface also allows access to form controls individually by `#id` or `[name]` as well.

```
   /* Event Object */
   .target // what the user clicked, changed, etc
   .currentTarget // the element (aka tag) that listens for event
   event handler // term for the function that's bound to listener
   /* HTMLForms 
   <form id='UI'>
   <input id='A0' name='A'>
   <input id='B0' name='A'>
   */
   cont UI = document.forms.UI // ref form
   cont io = UI.elements // ref all of form fields
   cont input1 = io.A0 // ref first input
   cont allInputs = [...io.A] // ref all [name='A'] as an array
```

**References**

[Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events)

[Event Delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)

[HTMLFormElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement)

```js
const addRow = () => {
  const table = document.querySelector('table').tBodies[0];
  const copy = table.rows[0].cloneNode(true);
  const inp = copy.querySelector('input');
  inp.value = '';
  copy.querySelectorAll('td')[2].innerHTML = `<button name='rem' type='button'>Remove Row</button>`;
  table.appendChild(copy);
  inp.focus();
};

const sum = array => {
  return array.map(inp => +inp.value).reduce((sum, cur) => sum + cur);
};

const manageData = e => {
  const io = e.currentTarget.elements;
  const btn = e.target;

  if (btn.matches('button')) {
    switch (btn.name) {
      case 'add':
        addRow();
        break;
      case 'calc':
        let X = [...io.x];
        io.total.value = sum(X);
        break;
      case 'rem':
        btn.closest('tr').remove();
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
};

const switchRow = e => {
  const sel = e.target;
  if (sel.name === 'y') {
    let inp = sel.parentElement.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild;
    if (sel.value === '0') {
      inp.disabled = false;
      inp.name = 'x';
    } else {
      inp.disabled = true;
      inp.name = '_';
    }
  }
};

const UI = document.forms.UI;
UI.onclick = manageData;
UI.onchange = switchRow;
```

```html
<form id='UI'>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input name='x' type='number'></td>
        <td>
          <select name='y'>
            <option value='0'>Enabled</option>
            <option value='1'>Disabled</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td><button name='add' type='button'>Add Row</button>
        </td>
        <td><button name='calc' type='button'>Total</button></td>
        <td><input name='total' readonly></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</form>
```